# Why is my machine slowing down?

Tags: 15.04

Everything was great when I got it. Now simple things like switching between tabs in Chrome can take 30 seconds. Opening up my Download folder also takes a long time.

System:

- Ubuntu 15.04
- 7.7 GiB
- Intel Core i5-3210M CPU @ 2.5 GHz x 4
- 64-bit
- 484.4 GB w/ 292.6 GB free

What can I try to regain speed?

Comment: did you mess with swappiness?

Comment: When did you last reboot?

Comment: You can clean browser(s) with BleachBit

Comment: Didn't mess with swappiness.
Rebooted over a week ago. How often should I be doing it?
Cleaned with BleachBit.

Speed has definitely returned. Thank you.